# Modern OpenGL C camera

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, perspectivecamera

I have a simple C program that I am trying to implement a third person camera in. My question is how to implement a camera using modern OpenGL. My major source of confusion is how to pass the transformations to the GPU, and what exactly lookat and perspective are supposed to do in regards to the view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation usually is passed as a set of transformation matrices to the GPU via a uniform (glUniform calls with the target shader program being bound). The contents of the transformation matrices are modelview, normal projection matrices; how these matrices are constructed can be found in every 3D graphics textbook, but also in the specifications of OpenGL-1.x and OpenGL-2

Comment: Thanks I solved my problem. I had the matrices, but was having trouble passing them to the gpu.

Comment: http://docs.gl/gl3/glUniform glUniformMatrix4fv(GLint   location,
  GLsizei   count,
  GLboolean   transpose,
  const GLfloat *  value);